# Escaping a PHP exec cmd containing quotation marks

Tags: php, exec

I am using the command below via PHP `exec` to run the Linux 64bit CLI version of a program called [Stereo Tool](https://www.stereotool.com/).

The command works and processes the audio file as expected, but the output contains an audiowatermark signalling that the license key I have used doesn't cover the features allowed in the preset I'm specifying (much as it would if I wasn't supplying a license key at all).

The preset has been checked and my license absolutely covers everything used within which leads me to believe that I'm not escaping the license key string correctly. The software requires that the key is contained within quotation marks, which I thought I was doing in my command but maybe not?

This is the command :

```
$cmd = PROGRAMS_DIR . "stereo_tool $input $output -s $preset -k \"$key\"";
exec($cmd);
```

And the `$key` variable is in the form of :

```
$key = '<12345678901234567890>';
```

Can anybody see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Use [`escapeshellarg()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg) on _all_ of the arguments individually, and you don't have to worry about escaping anything yourself.

Comment: If it's really on Windows, you might have to experiment with `^` caret escaping though. Sounds more like a bug however. Or did the result match up when tested from the command line?

Comment: I tried escaping the entire string before anything else, again, it worked but I still got the beep. Must be software related then.